# PowerBI Dashboard chat window customisation

Tags: html, user-interface, powerbi

Is it possible to customize the appearence of the popup that is appearing from the powerbi dashboard online view while we click on the ask button in a dashboard?

ask Image Icon would like to know the UI customization options for the qa popup. Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

There are no customisation available, the Q&A box is hard baked in to the PowerBI Service which is fully locked down as far as customisation go.

Further decent reading on the Q&A feature:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-visualization-introduction-to-q-and-a
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-q-and-a